# How to display a image in any format from a SQL LONGBLOB in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to read a image from a field LONGBLOB in a SQL table, and then display it in a HTML document. The query is made with php.
The code example:

```
<?php
    foreach(.....):
?>

<?php header("Content-type: image/jpg"); // For jpg
echo "<td>" .$p['imagen'] . "</td>"; // The image must be in a SQL BLOB or LONGBLOB  
?>

<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

But this just works for jpg images, and my database also contains png images. Can anybody tell me how to read images in a SQL LONGBLOB in any format?

And another question, this may cause slowness troubles in a free server? I've heard that using base64 may cause performance problems specifically if the LONGBLOB contains ñ or accents.

It could be read the format of the image in the LONGBLOB and using it to change the line 5?

Answer (score 1):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '*your_database_name*');

$imgQuery = ("SELECT FROM *your_table_name* WHERE *imageName* = 'theImageYouWant'");
$imgResult = mysqli_query($conn, $imgQuery);
$imgRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imgResult);
echo"<img src='".$imgRow['profileImage']."'>";
```

This is from an assignment im currently working on as of right now. However i'm using XAMPP and phpMyAdmin as a mysqli database. Thus the $conn variable is using my localhost, root folder etc. You should not have to change the localhost and root unless you're not using XAMPP, else I'm not sure. I've been doing php for about 5-6 months only. So I hope this can be of help to you in some way. :)

Comment: Is there a way to make it with PDO?

Comment: I just looked up what that is, and well....I don't know, from the looks of the documentation probably yeah you could. However like I said I'm not highly experienced with php stuff, so this is the best I can do for you I think.